# How to define css selector properties dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to define css selector properties dynamically ?

For example how to define "color" property of ".some-style" selector with the value got from the backend server?

```
<style>
    .some-style {
        color: #ffc050;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: please give more details about your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a dynamic `style` in your top-most element in your template.
2. Assign the backend response of your properties to a computed function.
3. Set style lang to `lang='scss'` then use CSS varialbe function `var()` to set the values.

Example

```
<template>
    <div :style="cssProps">
        <div class="some-style">
            Hello Mars
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
computed: {
    cssProps() {
        // backend response with your css values
        let backendResponseObject = {
            fontColor: "black", // you can use rgb or hex
            backgroundColor: "White" // you can use rgb or hex
        }

        properties = {
            "--brand-base": backendResponseObject.color,
            "--brand-primary": backgroundColor.hex,
        };

        return properties;
    }
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.some-style {
    color: var(--brand-base);
    background: var(--brand-primary);
}
</style>
```

Comment: **Set style lang to lang='scss' then** Actually you don't have to use scss. just that I've always used this in `<style lang="scss">`